# Apache reverse-proxy transforms POST requests into GET requests

Tags: apache, jenkins, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to analyse code using SonarQube, from a Jenkins job, and my job fails when a request get a 405 error. Apache is basically changing a POST request into a GET request, making the job fail.

Here's my apache vhost configuration:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

      ServerName public.dev
   Redirect permanent / https://public.dev/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard_cnp_dev.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard_cnp_dev.key

      ServerName public.dev

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost on

   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

   <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/sonar-https-error.log
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /var/log/httpd/sonar-https-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When the job fails, I get this console output:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 18.627s
INFO: Final Memory: 46M/112M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 405 on https://public.dev/api/ce/submit?projectKey=java-sonar-runner-simple&projectName=Simple%20Java%20project%20analyzed%20with%20the%20SonarQube%20Runner
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:32)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:96)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:67)
    at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:157)
    at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(PhaseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:238)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The 405 error is caused because SonarQube is receiving a GET request instead of a POST one (normal behaviour). I can see it on both the Apache and Sonar access logs:

```
APACHE
192.168.100.7 - - [01/Feb/2016:09:03:06 -0500] "GET /api/ce/submit?projectKey=java-sonar-runner-simple&projectName=Simple%20Java%20project%20analyzed%20with%20the%20SonarQube%20Runner HTTP/1.1" 405 51 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.5.1"

SONAR
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2016:09:14:08 -0500] "GET /api/ce/submit?projectKey=java-sonar-runner-simple&projectName=Simple%20Java%20project%20analyzed%20with%20the%20SonarQube%20Runner HTTP/1.1" 405 51 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.5.1"
```

This works when I don't use Apache as a reverse-proxy. Jenkins is on one machine, and both Apache and SonarQube are on another one.

Any ideas why this might be happening, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put an Apache reverse proxy in front of Sonar, and then access it from Jenkins, then you should add a context to the URL.  On the sonar server, edit your sonar.properties file and edit the following property to add a context.  The context can be anything...here's mine:

```
sonar.web.context=/quality
```

Then from within Apache edit your proxy settings.  Here's mine:

```
    ProxyPass /quality http://another-machine:9000/quality keepalive=on
    <Location /quality>
            ProxyPassReverse http://another-machine:9000/quality
    </Location>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue except I have an NGINX rule instead of apache.. Any idea how do it on NGINX?

My code goes as follows : `server {
    listen         80;
    server_name sonar.company.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}`